# Ratio of two quadratic vector forms

Tags: linear-algebra

This is probably a very basic question. Suppose we have two $n \times n$ positive definite real matrices A and B, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What is the value of following ratio as a function of $x$?

$ \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} $

Suppose that we define the value to be $0$ at $x=\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a degree-$2$ homogeneous positive bounded rational function of $(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$. There's nothing much else you can say in general: the value will vary between the smallest and largest eigenvalue ratios of $A$ and $B$: that is, since $A,B$ are positive-definite, there are positive numbers such that
$$ c \lVert x \rVert^2 \leqslant x^T Ax \leqslant C \lVert x \rVert^2, d \lVert x \rVert^2 \leqslant x^T Bx \leqslant D \lVert x \rVert^2, $$
and then clearly
$$ \frac{c}{D} \leqslant \frac{x^T Ax}{x^T Bx} \leqslant \frac{C}{d}, $$
with these only attained if the eigenspaces coincide.